# precedence and associatives in C

Tags: c

In a code segment, I saw this uncompacted form :

```
while(p1>=str1)
 {
  *p2 = *p1;
  p1--;
  p2++;
}
```

while the compacted form looks something like this :

```
 while(p1>=str1)
 {
   *p2++ = *p1--;
 }
```

what the code does is like clearly shown in the uncompacted form, it first copies the contents of the pointers before incrementing the p2 and decrementing the p1 but how could that be given that the ++  precedence is higher than the assignment operator in C? I thought there could be some () operator to force this but in the book it is correct. Can anyone explain this ? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The precedence simply affects how the code is parsed, that is, what the `++` refers to.  That why this:

```
*p2++ = *p1--;
```

is equivalent to this:

```
(*(p2++)) = (*(p1--));
```

But the semantics of `++` are to evaluate to the original value, and then later to increment the value.  So the assignment will use the old values of `p1` and `p2`, and then after the assignment is performed, will increment and decrement them.

Comment: but why are the brackets not used then in this case? I thought the brackets should have been used for without them, the syntax is not that correct;and this is the question, why is the syntax correct?

Comment: The syntax is correct because the postfix operators don't count as part of the statement evaluation until after the statement is evaluated (not exactly correct, but an easy way to think about it). In fact, though I'm not sure if this is also the case with C, I remember reading that postfix operators aren't recommended for use in C++ because they cause a temporary copy of the variable the operator is applied to to be produced, assumedly in order to utilize the old value while allowing the new value to be stored.

Answer (score 1):

`p2++` expression yields the value of `p2` and not `p2 + 1`. The increment operation is done a the sequence point.

Answer (score 1):

The `++` and `--` postfix operators take effect after the statement they are included in is performed. The precedence affects how tokens are grouped and how the syntax tree (I'm probably using the wrong vocabulary here) for the statement is generated.

Basically, `*p2++ = *p1--;` is equivalent to `*p2 = *p1; p2 += 1; p1 -= 1;`

Do be careful with the post- and prefix operators, though; doing something like `p2 = p1++ * p1--;` is considered undefined behavior, I believe.

Comment: `(p1++)--` is not valid in C as `p1++` is not a lvalue.